# Help with creating procedural aged golden material?

Tags: texturing, materials, objects, procedural

I'm a beginner to procedural textures and have spent the past few weeks studying it and now I'm wanting to practice making my own.

I'm trying to replicate the texture of this coffee table (shown below) but I keep running into issues creating the rust/burnt kind of gold texture (sorry, not sure how to explain with correct terms).

If someone could point me in the right direction to create this kind of rust and the different coloring I'd be very thankful.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add the result you have so far. And perhaps an image of your node setup.

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi, here (https://i.imgur.com/1WWE7QV.jpeg) is what I have so far, not really where I'd like to be but I know I am missing some step somewhere just not sure where.

Comment: @bacon add information to your post by editing it, don't post it in the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this. It's just 2 Noise textures, one multiplied (to transfer the darks) and the other added (to transfer the whites), both mixed with an orange basecolor, which when combined with a high metallic value gives the cooper-ish look similar to your reference image. You can change the amount of light/dark by adjusting theColorRamps. As an additional factor, I mixed the 2 Noise Textures and combined the result with black for a roughness factor, and adjusted the mix factor until it was sufficiently "shiny but grungy".

[image: Material]

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your clear advice. I appreciate the photo visual as I'm a visual learner. It looks really close to what I want it to look like especially the rusts. I will try your nodes out. I was unsure how to do the different rust/grunge parts but you explained well. I appreciate it!